# Установка openvpn на vps ubuntu 16.04

Tags: linux, ubuntu, openvpn

Проблема такая, что с самого начала установки всё пошло не так. После команды установки apt-get openvpn openssl easy-rsa iptables bash-completion, не могу перейти в директорию для установки по пути cd etc/openvpn/easy-rsa/ 
Ошибка: No such file or directory
Возможно, что-то не установлено, так как сервер новый, полностью чистый. Не могу найти решение проблемы, помогите!

Comment: Этого каталога в составе openvpn никогда и не существовало, конечно вы в него не перейдёте просто так

Comment: Забыл уточнить, что после mkdir ничего не меняется

Comment: В таком случае на всякий случай напоминаю, что `/etc/openvpn/easy-rsa/` и `etc/openvpn/easy-rsa/` это разные каталоги

Comment: давай начнем с того есть ли у тебя права на установку?
ты сделал apt install openvpn?